# React Native get position of element relative to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I need to get the position of an Animated View component which is inside of another View (which dimensions doesnt's match with the device's ones) every time I move it. I have tried with "onLayout" prop but I only get the information during the first render.

Also, I have tried to go on calling this function every time I move the component:

```
  // This function get the X/Y position of a specific node
  const measureNode = (node) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      UIManager.measure(node, (x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        resolve({ pageX, pageY }); // Having problems on android with offsets so use "pageX" and "pageY"
      });
    });
  };
```

But with this I get the position relative to the device's screen and not the parent.

Any ideas?

### UPDATE

Using

```
const measureNode = (node) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    UIManager.measure(node, (x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
      resolve({ x, y }); // Having problems on android with offsets
    });
  });
};
```

works fine on iOS but on android the offsets y and x are 0

### TRY IT YOURSELF

https://snack.expo.io/@victoriomolina/measure-issue-android

Comment: I think that the solution is to use x and y instead of pageX and pageY but I am getting undefined on android when I try to use those values

Comment: Maybe getting the parent's positions and subtracting them will work.

Comment: I think this is an issue of react native. I have opened an https://snack.expo.io/@victoriomolina/measure-issue-android so anyone can test it. Just try on iOS and see the results. Then, try on Android (where doesn't work)

Comment: But if you can get parent Y and child Y, you can calculate relative parentY - childY, am I right? Also I found that there was similar problem with that before.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22443

Comment: Yeah I am going to do this right now a close the thread. I opened a bug report on GitHub 
 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29526 . Maybe, this will be useful for someone in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use those functions I've implemented to get the relative-to-parent position.

```
  // This function measures specific nodes on the layout
  const measureNode = (node) => {
    /* 
       BUG - In the current React Native version (v. 0.61.4)
      the x and y values are wrong on Android devices. So, I have decided to
      use pageX and pageY (which are relative to the device's screen) and then
      implement my own method for getting relative-to-parent positions.

      https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29526
    */
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      UIManager.measure(node, (x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        resolve({ x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY });
      });
    });
  };

  const getRelativeToParentPosition = async (childNode, parentNode) => {
    // Get the relative-to-screen position of the child node
    const { pageX: childX, pageY: childY } = await measureNode(childNode);

    // Get the relative-to-screen position of the parent node
    const { pageX: parentX, pageY: parentY } = await measureNode(parentNode);

    /*
      Substract those values to get the relative-to-parent position.
      Pd: The child's position will be greater than the parent's one,
      just because the chlid is inside the parent.
    */

    return {
      x: childX - parentX,
      y: childY - parentY,
    };
  };
```